# Dynamically change data slot in 'SpatialGridDataFrame'

Tags: r, spatial

Let's say I have 'SpatialGridDataFrame'.

```
grd <- GridTopology(c(0,0), c(10,10), c(10,20))

grdx = SpatialGridDataFrame(grd, d=data.frame(www))
```

where 'www' is num [1:200] 1010 1010 1010 1009 1009 ... (200 obs. of 1 variable)

I would like to change g$www and remember all realizations with different name.
For example, if I make

```
r <- replicate(15,rnorm(10*20,mean=0,sd=3))   # matrix 200x15 with random numbers
m <-(matrix(nrow=200,ncol=15))
for (i in 1:15){
m [,i] <-  g[[1]] + r[,i]}    # matrix 200x15 with INPUT values for g$www
```

At the end I would like to have:

'SpatialGridDataFrame' g_1 with g$www = m[,1];

'SpatialGridDataFrame' g_2 with g$www = m[,2];

'SpatialGridDataFrame' g_3 with g$www = m[,3]; etc.

Thanks!